# during cast of a char value in java question mark is printed on console

Tags: java, casting

In the following program, can't char primitive neglect the _ve sign during casting of the int value...

```
public class CharConsole {

    public static void main(String[] er) {
        char a = (char) 65;
        char b = (char) -65;
        char c = (char) 98;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's likely that the console doesn't have a character that it can print from the available font that the console use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `char` can't be negative, so when you write:

```
char b = (char) -65;
```

you have an overflow and the actual value is `65,536 - 65`. You can verify it with

```
System.out.println((int) b);
```

which prints: `65471`

That character is probably not handled by your console and could appear as a blank or a square for example.

Answer (score 0):

What do expect here? The character int values map to character encoding table.  There is no negative table mapping.  It will always display a question mark as the requested character code is out of the encoding table range...

Comment: the character is not negative.

Comment: My answer explains why it can't be negative ... why did this got down voted?

Comment: `b` is not negative and it maps to a valid character. It just does not print on a console.

Comment: For example if you use `char b = (char) -65470;`, it will print `B`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what "convert an int to char".

If you simply want to cast the value in the int, you can cast it using Java's typecast notation:

```
int i = 97; // 97 is 'a' in ASCII
char c = (char) i; // c is now 'a'
```

but -ve is not any ASCII char value and does not represent any char

we can cast back

```
char b=(char)-65;
int i = (int)b;
```

print I it will be 65471